# VBA (instagram how to click follow button)?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, webautomation

I am using office 2019. in VBA i am trying to click on follow button. on INSTAGRAM but it did't click on that. simply page open and then nothing will happen.
so, plz help me because it is spine of my project.

```
Sub one()


Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim ele As IHTMLElement


Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 1
IE.navigate "https://www.instagram.com/gal_gadot/"

Do
Loop Until IE.readyState = 4

Set doc = IE.document

'doc.getElementsByTagName("button").innerText
'doc.getElementsByClassName("_5f5mN       jIbKX  _6VtSN     yZn4P   ").innerText

For Each ele In doc.getElementsByTagName("span")
   ' If InStr(ele.innerText, "Follow") > 0 Then ele.Click
    On Error Resume Next
    If ele.Value = "Follow" Then
    ele.Click
    End If
Next

For Each ele In doc.getElementsByTagName("button")
   ' If InStr(ele.innerText, "Follow") > 0 Then ele.Click
    On Error Resume Next
    If ele.Value = "Follow" Then
    ele.Click
    End If
    Next


End Sub
```

HERE IS HTML FILE

```
<span class="BY3EC  bqE32">
<span class="vBF20 _1OSdk">
<button class="_5f5mN       jIbKX  _6VtSN     yZn4P   ">Follow</button></span>
<span class="mLCHD _1OSdk">
<button class="_5f5mN       jIbKX KUBKM      yZn4P  m4t9r ">
<div class="OfoBO">
<div class="_5fEvj coreSpriteDropdownArrowWhite">
</div>
</div>
</button>
</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a bot to follow Gal Gadot on Instagram?!

Comment: No this is sample script. my task is another

Answer (score 0):

The script will help you click on that follow button but you can't follow her until you log in because when you click on that button, it will lead you to the log in page. Btw, you should always define any timed loop so that you can get out of that `do loop` in case the element is not available. There are several posts in SO which have got it covered.

```
Sub FollowGalGadot()
    Const Url$ = "https://www.instagram.com/gal_gadot/"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, post As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate Url
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
            Set post = .document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='follow'] > button")
            On Error GoTo 0
        Loop While post.Length = 0

        post.item(0).Click

    End With
    Stop
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Brother this code is not working wellhey did't click on follow button.

Comment: And i sloved the login  issue by allready login in another ie browser and continue open it but my friend this script is still not click on follow button plzz its my humble request  plzz help me.

Comment: Are you sure it is not working? Okay, where do you think the click is being initiated?

Comment: yes i am sure and i am also send u a screenshot in a link.

Comment: and it click on the follower button

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, SIM! I’m not a programmer, but I made a little change and it worked great!

```
Sub FollowGalGadot()
    Const Url$ = "https://www.instagram.com/gal_gadot/"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, post As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate Url
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        While post Is Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:001")
            Set post = .document.querySelector("._5f5mN.jIbKX._6VtSN.yZn4P")
            If Not post Is Nothing Then
                post.Click
                Debug.Print "it's done!!!"
            Else:
                Debug.Print "trying again"
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        Wend

    End With
    Stop
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```